# CakePHP User Subscription

Tags: php, cakephp

I am working on a social network type application and want a feature like Subscription in it.

Example:

If User A subscribes User B then User A should only be able to view posts made by User B and not the posts made by other Users.

In my point of view there will be a table for Subscriptions having field for ID, UserFrom, UserTo.

Now i am stucked in making a condition that allows a User to view only the posts of Subscribed users.

Need a bit of help please...

Comment: I just need an idea about it first. I am going to start in a while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get all User Ids list to whom logged in user subscribe in `beforeFilter` function so you can use it any where in controllers.

For example :  `UserA subscribe UserB ,UserD`  then check in `post view action If post author id is in subscribe array then allow to view else redirect to another action with message`.

thanks

Comment: So this is how i got you.

I have a table for Users, Posts and Subscribers.

Subscribers Table fields are: ID, USER_FROM, USER_TO
Posts Table fields are: ID, USER_ID, POSTS

So would it be like this? Subscribers.User_From = User.id and Subscribers.User_To = Post.User_Id ???

So what i think will happen is that first it will check from Users table that if the user is registered or not and then from the second condition it will take out all the fields from Posts table in which User_id is the same as in User_From field.... Right?

Comment: If you want to display listing of posts posted by users to whom logged in users subscribe. then check If Subscribers.User_From = User.id AND Fetch Subscribers.User_To. And check If Subscribers.User_To are active then display all Post from Posts table by Check Post.user_id = Subscribers.User_To.

Comment: And If you want that when user click on any post link then only post whose author is subscribed by logged in user then Check If Subscribers.User_To = Post.user_id and User.Id = Subscribers.User_From